# Ошибка в логике javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать возврат высоты элемента в начальное состояние?

пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kiiotory/e40gce56/8)

```
var memoria = $('.menu__drop').height();

$('.children_menu__list').hover(function() {
    $('.children_menu__drop', this).show();

    var menuDropInner = $('.children_menu__drop', this).height();
    var menuDrop = $('.menu__drop').height();
    var result = 0;

    if(menuDropInner > menuDrop) {
        result = $('.menu__drop').height(menuDropInner);  
    } else {
        result = $('.children_menu__drop').height(menuDrop);
    }

    return result;

}, function() {
    $('.children_menu__drop', this).hide();
    $('.menu__drop').height(memoria); // не срабатывает корректно
});
```

Comment: А где css и логика?

Comment: на Jsfiddle выложил, думал тм удобнее будет смотреть

Comment: Благодарю за исправления

Comment: Чё-то я не понимаю, `return result;` куда возвращается? Да и походу это всё меню можно только на css сделать без скриптов. Налицо какой-то огромный костыль

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `hover` в html атрибут style записалось значение большего размера списка и при наведении на меньший список в `menuDropInner` записывалось старое значение.

Просто удаляем из атрибута это значение `$('.children_menu__drop').height('');`

```js
memoria = $('.menu__drop').height();

$('.children_menu__list').hover(function() {
    $('.children_menu__drop', this).show();
  
    menuDropInner = $('.children_menu__drop', this).height();
    menuDrop = $('.menu__drop').height();
  
    if(menuDropInner > menuDrop) {  
        $('.menu__drop').height(menuDropInner);
    } else {
        $('.children_menu__drop').height(menuDrop);
    }
        
},  function() {
    $('.children_menu__drop', this).hide();
    $('.children_menu__drop').height('');
    $('.menu__drop').height(memoria);
});
```

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu__drop{

    background-color: aquamarine;
}
.side{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
/*    padding: 10px;*/
    background-color: #f0f;
}

.menu a{
    background: #3d3d3d;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu a:hover{
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}
.bgc-gray{
    position: relative;
}
.children_menu__drop{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="side">
       <ul class="menu">
       <li class="menu__list">
           <a href="#0" id="mag">Hey there</a>
           <div class="bgc-gray">
<!--              menuDrop-->
               <ul class="menu__drop">
                   <li><a href="#0">homepage</a></li>
                   
                   <li class="children_menu__list">
                      <a href="#0" id="office">Push me first and after link 2</a>
<!--                      menuDropInner-->
                       <ul class="children_menu__drop">
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                       </ul>
                       
                   </li>
                   <li  class="children_menu__list">
                      <a href="#0">Link_2</a>
                       <ul  class="children_menu__drop">
                           <li><a href="#0">some text</a></li>
                          
                       </ul>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </li>
       
   </ul>
</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"       integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Смысл в фоне за меню который будет изменяться сам в зависимости от количества элементов в списке, без правки CSS.

Comment: @Kiiotory, это нужно было в вопрос добавлять. Что конкретно нужно?

Comment: При наведении на один из блоков  заполняется background  в зависимости от наибольшей высоты ul или li, при наведении на блок с большей высотой  все ок( backgorund появился и исчез), а посля наведения на блок у которого только один элемент li, проверка при следующем наведении уже не выполняется. В jsfiddle есть блок с надписью push me first который илюстрирует проблему(да кстати return действительно не нужен спасибо)

Comment: @Kiiotory, навели на 'push me first' и появилась заливка. Навели на ul с одним элементом, убрали курсор и заливка снизу у списка должна убраться?

Comment: навели на push me first -> появилась заливка выравнивающая нижнюю границу основного списка и вложенного(в случае с push me first она добавляет к основному ul в высоте, в случае с Link 2 она добавляет заливку к li) P.s.да должно быть как вы указали, только как видно после срабатывания на нижнем элементе, на верхнем перестает работать

Comment: @Kiiotory, [так](http://i.stack.imgur.com/18fMO.gif) должно быть?

Comment: <https://www.microsoft.com/uk-ua/> аналогичное меню тут,    когда у нас появляется всего лишь один элемент li то заливка после него должна дойти всего лишь до конца списка ul слева, а в том варианте который сейчас у меня полагаю происходит запись высоты списка и дальнейшая проверка не проходит

Comment: @Kiiotory, [Вот так](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YSIFB.gif)?

Comment: Да нужно именно так

Comment: @Kiiotory, код отвратительно написан, очень трудно было разобраться. И всё же это можно как-то на css сделать, просто спать уже пора

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!